# I don't understand how the @ConversationScoped annotation works in CDI

Tags: java, cdi, conversation-scope

I'm using the following code to test the operation of ConversationScoped, but I don't understand how it works. I open conversation, set the value of conversationBean.i = 1, then close conversation and open a new conversation, but the value of conversationBean.i is still 1, why? it was supposed to be null, wasn't it?

```java
@WebServlet(value = "/tes")
public class MyTag extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    ConversationBean conversationBean;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,
                         HttpServletResponse resp) {
        conversationBean.startConversation();
        conversationBean.doSomething();
        conversationBean.out();
        conversationBean.endConversation();
        conversationBean.startConversation();
        conversationBean.out();
    }
}

@ConversationScoped
class ConversationBean implements Serializable {
    int i = 0;
    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;
    public void startConversation() {
        conversation.begin();
    }
    public void doSomething() {
        i++;
    }
    public void out() {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    public void endConversation() {
        conversation.end();
    }
}
```

Tell me, maybe I got it wrong? If so, could you provide an easy example where it really shows that when closing a conversation, all the resources associated with it are cleared?

Answer (score 0):

`@ConversationScoped` is primarily about JSF, in which context the word "conversation" has a particular meaning.  I haven't really used it, but I expect that it would sometimes make sense for the backing bean of a JSF component.

`Conversation` objects provide a way to access certain properties of JSF conversations.

> I open conversation, set the value of conversationBean.i = 1, then close conversation and open a new conversation, but the value of conversationBean.i is still 1, why?

The injected `ConversationBean` instance may change from request to request, but the one observed by a given invocation of one of your servlet's request-handling methods will not change during the execution of that method.  Naturally, then, if you modify that bean's state during `doGet()` then you can observe that modification later in `doGet()`.

Moreover, `Conversation.startConversation()` and `Conversation.endConversation()` don't do what their names might lead you to think they do.  They control whether the current conversation is "long-lived" or "transient", which affects its lifecycle, but they don't actually start or end a conversation.  The names make a little more sense if you think in terms of starting and ending *long-lived* conversations specifically, but even then they're not really right.  A single `setLongLived(boolean)` method would be more intuitive.

> it was supposed to be null, wasn't it?

No.

> Tell me, maybe I got it wrong?

You have incorrect expectations.

And although it's valid, it doesn't usually make sense to switch the current conversation back and forth between transient and long-lived multiple times while servicing the same request.  Request boundaries are *inside* conversation boundaries, so only the conversation type prevailing at the end of request processing matters.

> If so, could you provide an easy example where it really shows that when closing a conversation, all the resources associated with it are cleared?

That does not happen *per se*.  If you have a `@ConversationScoped` bean then you can expect to get different instances in different conversation contexts, but `Conversation.startConversation()` and `Conversation.endConversation()` don't get you a different conversation context for the current request. And if you hold on to a reference to a conversation-scoped bean past the end of the lifetime of the conversation context from which you obtained it, you should not expect that to cause its properties to be modified.